# Nhibernate add GAC assembly to mapping-by-code

Tags: nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping-by-code

I have `EmployeeEntity` stored in `MyCompany.Entities.Employee.dll` and `EmployeeMap: ClassMapping<SPListItem>` in `MyCompany.Mapping.dll`, both in GAC.

I use mapping-by-code to create ISessionFactory implementation like this:

```
var config = new Configuration();
// Initialize config code omitted... 
var mapper = new ModelMapper();
mapper.AddMapping(typeof(EmployeeMap));   
config.AddDeserializedMapping(mapping, "ExampleMapping");
// Exception thrown here:Could not compile the mapping document: ExampleMapping
// InnerException:persistent class KT.NHibernate.Mapping.Entities.Employee, KT.Nhibernate.Mapping.Entities not found
return config.BuildSessionFactory();
```

How should I properly configure Configuration instance to use GAC assemblies in my mapping?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that [there are solution](https://nhibernate.jira.com/browse/NH-2831)

> mapping.assembly = "MyCompany.Entities.Employee assembly strong name";

Answer (score 0):

This has nothing to do with GAC. You need to catch the exception and look at the inner exception to find out what is wrong - probably something in the mapping.

Comment: `persistent class KT.NHibernate.Mapping.Entities.Employee, KT.Nhibernate.Mapping.Entities not found`

Comment: Are all classes public and in either a locally deployed assembly or in the GAC?
You can also specify the full assembly qualified name including the public key token: KT.NHibernate.Mapping.Entities.Employee, KT.Nhibernate.Mapping.Entities, Version=xxx, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=xxx.

Comment: All classes are public, assemblies loaded into GAC (testsed with gacutil). Presented code run from ConsoleApplication. Specify full assembly name how? I tried `config.AddAssembly("MyCompany.Entities, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=0e3d5f149e92470e");` but still get same exception

Comment: OK, and do you have something like this on your .hbm.xml files:
<hibernate-mapping namespace="KT.NHibernate.Mapping.Entities" assembly="KT.NHibernate.Mapping.Entities" xmlns="urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2">